# The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.BindingsNmqiMQ' threw an exception

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

When trying to connect to MQ in bindings mode  (I have a server set up locally), I get the following exception:

```
 System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.BindingsNmqiMQ' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NativeManager.InitializeNativeApis(String mode)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.BindingsNmqiMQ..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment.GetInstance(String name)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment.GetMQI(Int32 id)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable properties)
   at Project.MQConnector.CreateConnectAndAddQueueManager(QueueManagerConnectionDetails connDetails)
```

The error occurs when trying to connect to a queue manager as follows:

Constructor:

```
Friend queueManagerConnectionProperties As New Hashtable()
queueManagerConnectionProperties.Add(MQC.THREAD_AFFINITY_PROPERTY, True)
If My.Settings.MQConnectAsClient Then
    queueManagerConnectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT)
Else
    queueManagerConnectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS)
End If

queueManagerConnectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK Or MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR) ' have handle-sharing with call blocking
```

And in the CreateConnectAndAddQueueManager method (where connDetails is just a store for the port, host, name, etc.):

```
 Dim specificQMConnProperties As Hashtable = CType(queueManagerConnectionProperties.Clone(), Hashtable)
 specificQMConnProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, connDetails.Channel)
 specificQMConnProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, connectionName)
 Dim qmgr As MQQueueManager = Nothing

 Try
     qmgr = New MQQueueManager(connDetails.Name, specificQMConnProperties)
 Catch ex As MQException
     ' error handling
 End Try
```

I have the following environment variable:

```
NMQ_MQ_LIB=mqm.dll
```

When I connect using a managed connection (`NMQ_MQ_LIB=managed`; and don't set the `MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY`), it works fine.

Any thoughts?

--Edit--

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\MQSI\9.0.0.2>dspmqver -a
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.5.0.6
Level:       p750-006-160226
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Windows
Mode:        32-bit
O/S:         Windows 7 Enterprise x64 Edition, Build 7601: SP1
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     No
InstPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
DataPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
MaxCmdLevel: 750
LicenseType: Production
AMQ8351: WebSphere MQ Java environment has not been configured correctly.
AMQ8351: WebSphere MQ Java environment has not been configured correctly.

Name:        IBM WebSphere MQ custom channel for Windows Communication Foundation
Version:     7.5.0.6
Level:       wn750-006-151116
Build Type:  Production


Name:        IBM Message Service Client for .NET (XMS .NET)
Version:     2.5.0.6
Level:       nn250-006-151116
Build Type:  Production


Name:        IBM Global Security Kit for WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.14.53
Build Type:  Production
Mode:        32-bit

Name:        IBM Global Security Kit for WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.14.53
Build Type:  Production
Mode:        64-bit
```

Comment: Do you have full MQ client installed or just running with amqmdnet.dll?

Comment: I have the full MQ installed (specifically, 7.5.0.6 - upgraded from 7.5.0.1 which came wiith IIB toolkit)

Comment: IF you can give me a way of checking more specifically what I have installed, that might be helpful

Comment: Dspmqver -a will list all components installed. But I don't see the need for setting NMQ_MQ_LIB. Application should work without it.

Comment: Even without it, I get the same problem

Comment: OK. Can you check if Windows Global Assembly Cache still has MQ .NET v7501 assemblies? TypeInitialization exception typically happens if required assemblies/dlls are not found.

Comment: It seems like I have 7.5.0.3 in C:\Windows\Assembly (is that where I should look?) - amqmdxxx are all v7.5.0.3. How do I go about fixing this? (Windows 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your latest comment. You have some unwanted entries in GAC. You need to do some clean up.

1) Open a command prompt.

2) Run `amqiregisterdotnet.cmd /u` command to unregister MQ .NET assemblies.

3) Check Windows GAC what MQ .NET assemblies. Make sure there are no MQ .NET entries. If there are some, try unregistering manually using `gacutil` command.

4) Then run the command `amqiregisterdotnet.cmd` to register the assemblies again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the following error running that command (from an IIB integration console): "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vb80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e183eb_8.0.50727.6195_none_cbf5e994470a1a8f\MCF80U.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support"

Comment: for amqidnet.exe, in the messagebox header. It appears five or six times

Comment: You are using wrong command. You need to run amqiregisterdotnet.cmd command as mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that, when I run `amqiregisterdotnet.cmd /u`, I get a messagebox, with the error from my first comment, and the title of the message box is `amqidnet.exe`

Comment: You seem to be missing some Visual Studio redistributables. Can you try manually removing MQ v7.5.0.3 assemblies from GAC?